# vue.js jwt token refresh with axios interceptors

Tags: vue.js

im trying to refresh users jwt token in vue.js.So my solution would be when the user send a request with expired token got rejected with status code 401 and then in axios intereceptors I try to refresh the token with sending a token refresh request to my backend. The problem is when the token refresh happens it didn't repeat the original request

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
  return response
  }, async function (error) {
    if(error.response.status===401){    
    let newtokens= await axios.post('RefreshToken',{
        oldtoken:store.state.user.token,
        refreshtoken:store.state.user.refreshtoken
    })
    let user=store.state.user
    console.log(user)
    user.token=newtokens.data.token
    user.refreshtoken=newtokens.data.refreshtoken
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']='Bearer '+ user.token
    console.log(newtokens)
    store.dispatch("user",user)
    console.log(store.state.user)  
    return axios(error.config)
}
  return Promise.reject(error)
})
```

I tried to console log what happens in the axios interceptors and it looks like it has been successfully send the request to the backend and refresh the user token. The only problem is it didn't repeat the original request

Answer (score 0):

if your axios version is between **(1.1.0) to (1.1.3)** then such issue occured but on downgrade to version (0.27.2) works well.
Github issue:https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5143

And it seems still issue hasn't been solved for higher version